# Alarm gets cleared on reboot in nadroid

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to post Data repeating after 7 days. for this I use Alarm Manager setRepeat method.As Alarm gets cleared when the phone reboot. I use boot receiver and setting the alarm again.

But if the phone gets reboot on 6th day and alarm gets set again,then alarm will ring on 6+7th day rather then it should rind on 7th day.
Is there any way solution for that??

Sorry for my poor English.
Please help

Comment: SharedPreferences may help you to store data on disk and read them later (e.g. after a reboot)

Answer (score 7):

When setting the alarm save the trigger time in shared Preference.And in on boot receiver set again the alarm but in this case trigger time comes from the shared preference.

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.Company.PackageName.BootCompletedReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

In Your com.Company.PackageName.BootCompletedReceiver Class

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    private Context mContext;
    private G9SharedPreferences oSharedPreferences;
    private AlarmManager amSchedules;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        oSharedPreferences = new G9SharedPreferences(this.mContext);
        try 
        {
            vUpdateAlarmManager();  
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            oSharedPreferences = null;
            this.mContext = null;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void vUpdateAlarmManager()
    {
        vCancelAlaramManager();
        Date dCurrentDate = new Date(oSharedPreferences.GetLongPreferences(G9Constant.BACKUP_TIME, 0));     
        if(dCurrentDate.getTime() < new Date().getTime())
        {
            dCurrentDate.setDate(dCurrentDate.getDate() + 1);
        }
        vSetRepeatingAlarm(dCurrentDate);
    }

    public void vCancelAlaramManager()
    {
        Intent oIntent = new Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent oPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, oIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(oPendingIntent);
        oPendingIntent.cancel();
    }

    public void vSetRepeatingAlarm(Date dScheduleTime)
    {
        amSchedules = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        amSchedules.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dScheduleTime.getTime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent);
    }
}
```